# Issues in displaying the image from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I uploaded the image to database, when i try to print it out(echo) on to the page it doesnt work, i saved the image path in the database, i even debugged it, the path is correct, but still it doesn't print,

this is my code to display the image:

```
    <?php
          if($row['images']) {
             $path = $row['images'];
             echo "<img src=\"$path\" class=\"image\" alt=\"\" style=\"border-radius: 20px;\">";
          } else {
             echo '<img src="images/default-avatar.png" class="image" alt="" style="border-radius: 20px;">';
          }
          
          ?>
```

this is my code to save the image:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $target_path = "images/";
        $target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);$host = "localhost";
        $dbUsername = "root";
        $dbPassword = "";
        $dbName = "vvmat";

        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Could not connect to the database.');
        }
        else {
            
            $Insert = "INSERT INTO profile(Name,age,gender,religion,mother_tongue,caste,country,mobile_number,Landline,images,zodiac,email_id,Username,Password,ConfirmPassword) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($Insert);
            $stmt->bind_param("sisssssssssssss",$Namee,$age,$gender,$religion,$mother_tongue,$caste,$country,$mobile_number,$Landline,$target_path,$zodiac_path,$email_id,$Username,$Passwordd,$ConfirmPassword);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
                echo "New record inserted successfully.";
            }
            else {
                echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "All fields are required.";
        die();
    }
}
else {
    echo "Submit button is not set";
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p>photo upload <span>*</span></p>
      <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/*" required class="box">
        <div class="error error-txt"><h4>Kindly upload image in JPG or PNG format</h4></div>
      <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" class="btn"></form>
```

database image:

[image]

this is how the image looks now:

[image]

can you please tell me where im going wrong?? i'm trying to fix this for so long

Comment: `this is my code to save the image`...all that does is save the name of the image file into the database. You forgot the code to actually save the image file to disk. [Read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: P.S. As an aside, why are you storing the password twice in the database? That is completely pointless.

Comment: Oh yes! I did write code for to save the file to database, please can you send the code, I'm little lost, if you cant thats totally fine and yes i have to remove the confirm password too 
thank you for pointing it out

Comment: For clarity, you can't just use the filename from the `$_FILES` array, as that is a tempfile and will be removed as soon as the script ends. You must use `move_uploaded_file()` to move it to a permanent location.